# Sql help, function parses a string field in table, need to filter returned table in where clause

Tags: sql, string, function, oracle11g, jdeveloper

I need some help, I am using Oracle 11g 11.1.2.4, and Jdeveloper

I need the 'Type' returned from my function to be filtered in the where clause so that any 'Type' that is 'NO_TYPE' is not returned.

I have a SQL statement like the following:

```
Where 'String_Finder' is a function I created to parse the field in the table.
      'Log_Table' is the table I am accessing.
      'Message' is the field in the table I am parsing.
```

SQL:

```
Select
        String_Finder(Log_Table.Message, 1, 2) AS Type
From
        LOG Log_Table
Where
       [ this is where I need help --- I need to filter Type based on the word 'NO_TYPE']
```

My function:

```
"String_Finder" (p_message in VARCHAR2, first_field NUMBER, second_field NUMBER) RETURN AS VARCHAR2 AS

v_posA NUMBER;
v_posB NUMBER;

BEGIN
      v_posA := INSTR(p_message, '|', 1, first_field) + 1;
      v_posB := INSTR(p_message, '|', 2, second_field)

RETURN SUBSTR(p_message, v_posA, (v_posB - v_posA));
END;
```

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: Ok, I have updated I am using Oracle 11g 11.1.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should just be:

```
WHERE String_Finder(Log_Table.Message, 1, 2) NOT LIKE 'NO_TYPE'
```

Comment: When I do this I recive an invalid identifier.

Comment: When I move to the where clause it does not complain however my function does not return any results.

Comment: @Bman  So when you use the function in the select it returns a bunch of values which you can see, including NO_TYPE?  But when you put it in the where clause it returns nothing?

Comment: Ok, so I got it working the result was in the where clause String_Finder(Log_Table.Message, 1, 2) NOT LIKE 'NO_TYPE' works

Comment: so I rechecked my statement I was including String_Finder(Log_Table.Message, 1, 2) Message <> 'NO_TYPE' When I changed it to: String_Finder(Log_Table.Message, 1, 2) NOT LIKE 'NO_TYPE' it works. Thanks for your help!